# Getting error when using FirebaseUI-IOS with custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, firebase

I'm using [Firebase-UI-IOS](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS) for my iOS app. When i run the app i get the following error:

> fatal error: ”unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value”.

Here is my code in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com")
    var dataSource: FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource!
        let messageRef = ref
        .childByAppendingPath("brainstorms")
        .childByAppendingPath(invite.brainstormId)
        .childByAppendingPath("messages")

    self.dataSource = FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource(ref: messageRef, cellClass: MessageCollectionViewCell.self, reuseIdentifier: "messageCell", view: self.collectionView)

    self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UICollectionViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
        // Populate cell as you see fit
        if let cell = cell as? MessageCollectionViewCell {
            println(cell)
            cell.messageText.text = "Hello world" <--- ERROR HERE
        }
    }

    self.collectionView.dataSource = self.dataSource
```

I've tried to unwrap cell.messageText, but it always returns nil. My cell class `MessageCollectionViewCell` is registered in my Storyboard.

My `println(cell)` prints the following line: `<xxxxx.MessageCollectionViewCell: 0x7fc26d8d9080; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (17.5 155; 340 80); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc26d8d92e0>>`.

This looks to me like it should be working. Reference to `populateCellWithBlock` can be found [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseUI/Implementation/FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource.m#L130).

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creator of FirebaseUI here.

Looks like the FirebaseUI parts are working fine (our contract will return a populated cell that is a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and an object that is a subclass of `NSObject`, which appears to be working).

The issue seems to be that in your custom cell hasn't properly initialized the `UILabel`. Can you please post your `MessageCollectionViewCell.swift` file?

It should look something like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MessageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var mainLabel: UILabel?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Custom initialization code for label
        let size = self.contentView.frame.size
        let frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)
        self.mainLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)

        // Make sure you add the label as a subview
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.mainLabel!)
    }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Once you've got an `init(frame:)` call, it should populate appropriately.

I tested this out with the following `populateCellWithBlock`:

```
dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UICollectionViewCell, snap: NSObject) -> Void in
    let cell: MessageCollectionViewCell = cell as! MessageCollectionViewCell

    cell.mainLabel?.text = "Hello!"
}
```

I'm working on adding `__kindof` support to make the signature look more like:

```
dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: MessageCollectionViewCell, snap: Message) -> Void in
    cell.mainLabel?.text = "Hello!"
}
```

But support for `__kindof` seems to be spotty and not really working (XCode 7 Beta 5 claims to have support, but I can't get Cocoapods + Swift to accept it, even though it builds in XCode and works in Objective-C).

Let me know if you've got any other feedback on FirebaseUI, and if you see any other bugs, feel free to add them to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues) :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, this seems to be working. Is there any chance for me to keep the constraints that i have in Storyboard when using addSubview()?

Comment: If you use the XIB version of the constructor it'll pull everything in from the XIB where you've already created your constraints, no `init(frame: )` necessary (as it calls `awakeFromNib`).